# What is the meaning of the following method definition?

Tags: java, function, generics

What does the first part in the following method definition?

```
<I, O> MyReturnType<I, O> myMethod() { ... }
```

The second is the method'sreturn type, third is the method name, but what is the first one?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html

Comment: `<I,O>` is declaring generic type parameters for the function. It's saying "In the following definition, `I` and `O` are standing in for some types that depend on the situation when the method is called."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`I` and `O` are declared as generic type parameters. They're generic types introduced by the method itself, as said here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html

> Generic methods are methods that introduce their own type parameters. This is similar to declaring a generic type, but the type parameter's scope is limited to the method where it is declared. Static and non-static generic methods are allowed, as well as generic class constructors.

If you don't declare `<I, O>`, java will look for types called `I` and `O` (which won't be there, since they're supposed to be generic).

I think @khelwood put it nicely (see comments on original question):  It's saying: "In the following definition, I and O are standing in for some types that depend on the situation when the method is called."